# Its possible to have multiple scm section in my pom?

Tags: maven, release, maven-release-plugin, maven-scm

How can i have multiple configuration on my scm section in my pom.

Currently, i have this :

```
<scm>
    <connection>scm:git:ssh://xxxxx/xxx/xxx</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:[fetch=]ssh://xxxxx/xxx/xxx[push=]ssh://USERNAME@xxxxx/xxxx/Xxx</developerConnection>
    <url>http://xxxx/xxxx/Xxxx</url>
    <tag>HEAD</tag>
</scm>
```

i want to have with new USERNAME because when i use mvn release perform i have a access denied and username is the issue. The username writted is the username from other distance machine and i want to perform release from another with a new username.

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Configure it correctly in settings.xml and not in pom...

Comment: The doc configure it in pom https://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/usage.html

Answer (score -1):

I just need to use `-Dusername=your_scm_username` and its good !
More infos here
http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/usage.html